# Synonym for Dauntingness

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Looking for a synonym for dauntingness that's less a of a mouthful. Something that retains the meaning of "the quality of being terrifying or demoralizing"

- Example 1: Her ability to cause others to shake with her mere presence speaks of how high her dauntingness is.
- Example 2: His low dauntingness, inspires great confidences in his enemies.

Comment: What have you found in the dictionary that didn't suit your purposes?

Comment: Where have you seen this word used by a native speaker or writer of English?

Answer (score 1):

The word 'dauntingness' does not appear in the more credible dictionaries.

Looking for a synonym of 'daunting', the first example can be simplified to:

> Her ability to cause others to shake with her mere presence speaks of how intimidating she is.

In the second example, I am not familiar with 'daunting' being used as an absent characteristic, and would rephrase it in the opposite sense, with a positive characteristic:

> His approachability inspires great confidence in his enemies.

Note that 'confidence' is uncountable here, so does not take the plural form.

However, neither of the sentences really makes much sense.